# ngb range DatePicker get closed on every click not able to select date

Tags: angular

here is stackblitz  link :-   (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5fpxjn?file=src/app/datepicker-range-popup.ts)  Click [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5fpxjn?file=src/app/datepicker-range-popup.ts)
date picker get closed on each click on selection of date etc. , it just get  closed
Don't know why But when i import localiz/init in polyfils.ts then navigation is coming but one problem is coming with it , on every click ngb-datepicker get close not able to select in rang

When we remove shadowdom it is working fine , but when we are using shadowdom it start misbehaving

Comment: can you create a stackblitz example with your code

Comment: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/stackblitzes/datepicker/disabled/stackblitz.html
Place i copied here it is working

This is same Like This not Single variable name is changed ,but got problem navgation not coming then searched and found @angular/localize need to be import after it navigation month year selection is coming but even i import localize in pollyfils  but after importing it date picker getting closed 

here i am using latest bootstrap 5 and angular 12.2.14 and and ngb also installed 
but don't know it is happening ,

Comment: i found problem , because of shadowdom is enable that is why it get closed on each closed dont know why but is

Comment: here is LInk 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5fpxjn?file=src/app/datepicker-range-popup.ts